# WPF TabControl tabs "jumping"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I'm creating a WPF tab control which contains tabs rotated 270° When I mouse the mouse over between tabs they appear to be "jumping". I'm looking for a way to prevent this from happening.The tabs should have the same behaviour as the tabs in Microsoft Office ribbon UI(stay in a fixed position). Is it possible to modify the `XAML` below to achieve this?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="300" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" UseLayoutRounding="true">
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#330033" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9pt"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border Background="White" Name="Border" BorderBrush="#A9A9A9" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0">
                                    <Border Padding="2" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                        ContentSource="Header" 
                                        Margin="12,0,12,2"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TabItem Header="Tab item 1" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab item 2" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab item 3" />
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to hide a `Border` when the mouse is not over a tab by setting the `Border`'s `BorderBrush` to `Transparent` rather than setting its `BorderThickness` to zero.

In other words, change

```
<Border Background="White" Name="Border" BorderBrush="#A9A9A9" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0">
```

to

```
<Border Background="White" Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0">
```

and in the `IsMouseOver` trigger, use

```
    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A9A9A9" />
```

in place of a setter on the `BorderThickness`.

In your case, the border element itself changes size when you change its `BorderThickness` because the `BorderThickness` contributes to the 'size' of the `Border`, and the control inside it doesn't change size.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the below line (border) from the IsMouseOver trigger it stops jumping and visually it doesn't really have a huge effect (in my opinion).

```
<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0" />
```

Comment: Hello Richard, thanks but I do need the border to be shown on IsMouseOver, in a case where tab item background is White,I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: Right, then my answer won't work as you've said. I'd support Luke then with what he's said about making the Border transparent rather than setting it's thickness to zero.